# Spellcheck for Search API Database

Tags: views, search

I need the functionality of google like "Did you mean". There is no solution for **Search API Database**. Though it is available for Solar Search.

Is there some thing i can do with views to achieve this ?

Any suggestions please.

Thanks

Comment: I'm also interested in this.. did you find anything?

Comment: I changed to Acquia search, which provides Solar search with search API database . So the available module worked for me.